# Tricky mysql query related to the backpack issue

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say that we have a user request. That request contains a decimal number. That decimal number is correlated with a table in the database, it is lower than the summary of all values of the fields in a proper column. But the request is not the exact summary of any possible values from that column.

On the other hand - it is not possible to increase that value, but it is possible to reduce any value of the field in this column, so some possible number of values will create a sum, that will match the user's request.

That is the problem, and I don't understand how to solve it. Maybe someone ever has done something similar, and can help me find a way out?

I am not really hoping for this, and I understand that it is a complicated thing even to explain, but I would much appreciate the solution.

```
$wa = 0.001;
$address = $address;
function recursion($wa)
{
  $resulte = db_select ('Credit_user','c')
  ->fields ('c')
  ->range(0,1)
  ->orderby('cr_ts', 'ASC')
->condition('c.affected','0','=')
->condition('c.amount','0','!=')
 ->execute();
foreach($resulte as $item) {
  global $code = $item->redeem_code;
  global $amounte = $item->amount; 
global $wai = $wa - $amounte;
if ($wai < 0){  
  "production code that should operate with different variations of $amounte and $redeem on last iteration"
  return;
}
elseif ($wai >= 0){  "production code that should operate with different variations of $amounte and $redeem on each iteration"

  return;

} else {
  function recursion($wa - $amounte);
}
}

}
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample, your actual result, your expected  result and the code you are using

Comment: Also add the table schema(s) to your question.

Comment: Maybe start by reading [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: What do you mean by "summary of all values"? Did you mean "sum"?

Comment: What's the backpack issue?

Comment: Compare the requested number to `SUM(columnname)` and `SUM(columnname) - MAX(columnname)`. If the number is in between them, then you can reduce the value in the row with the max to create the requested sum.

Comment: I did uptated my question with what I've been doing with the code. Please explain me what am I doing wrong, if you know.